# Python matplotlib interval

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I'm using matplotlib in Python and I made a histogram with bars. Now when the histogram appears only the multiples of 5 appear on the x-axis and the multiples of 1000 appear on the y-axis. For the y-axis it's no problem at all but for the x-axis I want the interval to be 1 instead of 5 because I use 1 bar per hour. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
def plotHistogramTickets():

    hours_NumbersSold = dict()
    for i in range(24):
        hours_NumbersSold[i]=0
    soldTickets = db.getSoldTickets()
    for ticket in soldTickets:
        hourSold = ticket.timeBought.hour
        hours_NumbersSold[hourSold]+=1
    for k,v in hours_NumbersSold.iteritems():
        plt.bar(k,v,1,0)
    plt.xlabel("Hours")
    plt.ylabel("Numbers of tickets sold")
    plt.title("Numbers of tickets sold per hour")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xticks()`. The following should do the trick for you (put it before the `show()` command):

```
plt.xticks(range(25))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have the problem the x-values are till 25, I need 24 instead. Any idea?

Comment: That's strange, but if so, just replace `25` with `24`: `plt.xticks(range(24))`